# How can I remove super-potions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I've had my fun playing with Super Poitions (Fortify Intelligence to 2 million, Feater, etc)

I want to remove them. I've tried;

- waiting for the full length of time
- Looking for saved game editors
- using Dispel
- EnableStatReviewMenu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I've tried that worked was the console command RemoveEffects, for instance:

> player->RemoveEffects, 79

should remove any "fortify attribute" effects that are currently applied to you.

There's a complete list of effects the [RemoveEffects UESP page.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes3Mod:RemoveEffects)